# Why can't a choose a fixed height for my wrapper without affecting vertical alignment of children?

Tags: alignment, height, fixed

This has been bothering me. Although I've resolved my problem using padding for the container to create the desired height of the container, I'm still puzzled on why this happens.

I have a container with two child elements inside, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" id="first-item"/>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" id="second-item"/>
</div>
```

I vertical align the children to the container using the below:

```
#first-item, #second-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

However, if a fixed height is set for the container, the vertical alignment breaks.

**Why is this so?**

http://jsfiddle.net/Nx8Jc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you add a `line-height` property with an identical value to the `height`:

```
.container {
    background-color: #EADDBB;
    height: 100px; 
    line-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
}

#first-item, #second-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/galengidman/Nx8Jc/1/

Comment: Thanks for the line-height idea. I'll be using it to make my code more semantic. I appreciate the response, but the question still remains: Why don't elements vertically align to the fixed height of the container (without line-height)?

Comment: It's because `vertical-align` applies to the line, not the total height. It's where the element is in relation to where the text would be if there were text on the line. That's why it has values such as `baseline`, `text-top`, `text-bottom`, etc.

Comment: After your reply, I did more digging: "The vertical-align property in CSS controls how elements set next to each other on a line are lined up."

Thank you for your help Galen!